# setState() not updating the View - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Good day Guys,

I have just started using Reactjs for a project but am stuck in this issue and can do with some help. I am trying to implement an Order management system where orders are pushed to the browser using websockets and then a reactjs view is updated as par that data. There are associated events that are handled on the UI during interaction that should update the state of the Orders. Since i just started using Reactjs, i decided to hardcode my dataset so i can see the Orders displayed on a list. However i cant click on the list and get the details of that clicked item to refresh the view and show up on its allocated space, when the application starts only the list of Orders are displayed no detail view as shown in the code below or from http://jsfiddle.net/d5wvtyf0/. So the question is how can i make the view update and show the update that am making by calling setState() or maybe the question is what am i doing wrong in the code i have already?

```
/*This is a container for the title on the lefthand side - In Progress/Ready etc*/
var OrderItemsTitle = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <p className="row-progress">{this.props.title_text}</p>
        );
    }
});

OrderItemButtons = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="row-order " onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
                <img src={this.props.orderitem.image_url} />
                <span className="txt">{this.props.orderitem.cust_name}</span>
                <span className="status">{this.props.orderitem.time}</span>
            </a>
        );
    }
});

/*This is the component that loads the items on the leftside of the screen*/
var ListViewOrderItemsContainer = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(orderitem){
        this.props.onUserInput(orderitem);
        console.log(this.props.selectedorderitem);
    },
    render: function(){
        var filteredNewOrderItem = this.props.orderitems.filter(function(orderitem){
            return orderitem.status.toLowerCase().search('new') !== -1;
        });
        var filteredReadyOrderItem = this.props.orderitems.filter(function(orderitem){
            return orderitem.status.toLowerCase().search('ready') !== -1;
        });
        var filteredInProgressOrderItem = this.props.orderitems.filter(function(orderitem){
            return orderitem.status.toLowerCase().search('in_progress') !== -1;
        });


        return(
            <div className='leftContainer'>
                <OrderItemsTitle title_text='New' />
                <div className='new_progress_container'>
                    {
                        filteredNewOrderItem.map(function(orderitem, i){
                            return <OrderItemButtons key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,
                                orderitem)} orderitem={orderitem} selectedorderitem={this.props.selectedorderitem} />
                        }, this)
                    }
                </div>    
                <OrderItemsTitle title_text='In Progress' />
                <div className='in_progress_container'>
                    {
                        filteredInProgressOrderItem.map(function(orderitem, i){
                            return <OrderItemButtons key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 
                                orderitem)} orderitem={orderitem}/>
                        }, this)
                    }
                </div>
                <OrderItemsTitle title_text='Ready' />
                <div className='ready_container'>
                    {
                        filteredReadyOrderItem.map(function(orderitem, i){
                            return <OrderItemButtons key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 
                                orderitem)} orderitem={orderitem}/>
                        }, this)
                    }
                </div>    
            </div> 
        );
    }
});

/*This is the productline details that is shown on the righthand side of the OMS*/
var ProductItemLineDetails = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <p>                
                <span className="pull-right">
                    <strong>{this.props.productItem.productItemPrice}</strong>
                </span>
                <span className="text-muted">
                    <strong>{this.props.productItem.productItemName}</strong>
                </span>
            </p>
        );
    }
});

/*This is the container element for ProductItemLineDetails above*/
var ProductItemDetails = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log("this.props.orderitem.length = ", this.props.orderitem.length);
        var productRow;
        if (this.props.orderitem.length === 0){
            productRow = "";            
        }
        else {
            productRow = this.props.orderitem.products.map(function(product, i){
                return <ProductItemLineDetails key={i} productItem={product} />             
            });
            console.log("productRow = ", productRow);
        }

        return ( 
            <div>
                <div className="media">
                    <small className="pull-right">
                        23h ago
                    </small>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h4 className="media-heading">
                            Bruno Otas
                        </h4>
                        <span className="text-muted">
                            (234)-8087616915
                        </span> 
                        <br />
                        <span className="text-muted">
                            2 days ago at 2:30 am - 11.06.2014
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                    <hr />            
                    {productRow}
                    <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

/**This is the main container that houses everything on the right hand side of the view**/
var DetailViewOrderItemsContainers = React.createClass({
    render: function() {        
        return (
            <div className="rightContainer">
                <ProductItemDetails orderitem={this.props.selectedorderitem} />
            </div>    
        );
    }
});

var ParentContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            selectedorderitem: []
        }
    },
    handleUserInput: function(orderitem){
        this.setState({
          selectedorderitem: orderitem
        });
        console.log("setstate hit",  this.state.selectedorderitem);
        console.log("setstate order", orderitem);
      },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="parentContainer">
                <ListViewOrderItemsContainer orderitems={this.props.orderitems} 
                onUserInput={this.handleUserInput} 
                selectedorderitem={this.state.selectedorderitem} />
                <DetailViewOrderItemsContainers selectedorderitem={this.state.selectedorderitem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


//var inProgressOrderDetails = [
var orderitems = [
{id: "2942934-343323-234242234-23423",status: 'new', time: "2", image_url: "/assets/images/profile_small.jpg", cust_name: "Nnamdi Jibunoh", products:[{id: "2422-34333-34343", variants: [{productItemPrice:"1800", productItemName: "Ice Cream"}]}] },
{id: "2942934-343323-234242234-23424",status: 'new', time: "3", image_url: "/assets/images/profile_small.jpg", cust_name: "Adeolu Adamu", products:[{id: "2422-34333-34343", variants: [{productItemPrice:"1800", productItemName: "Ice Cream"}]}] },
{id: "2942934-343323-234242234-23425",status: 'in_progress', time: "4", image_url: "/assets/images/profile_small.jpg", cust_name: "Alaku Ishienyi", products:[{id: "2422-34333-34343", variants: [{productItemPrice:"1800", productItemName: "Ice Cream"}]}] },
{id: "2942934-343323-234242234-23426",status: 'ready', time: "5", image_url: "/assets/images/profile_small.jpg", cust_name: "Ogochukwu Maduabum", products:[{id: "2422-34333-34343", variants: [{productItemPrice:"1800", productItemName: "Ice Cream"}]}] },
{id: "2942934-343323-234242234-23427",status: 'ready', time: "6", image_url: "/assets/images/profile_small.jpg", cust_name: "Bruno Otas", products:[{id: "2422-34333-34343", variants: [{productItemPrice:"1800", productItemName: "Ice Cream"}]}] },
];

React.render(<ParentContainer orderitems = {orderitems} />, document.getElementById('react_body'));
```

Comment: If you are adding a fiddle, please make it work so we can see the code in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setState method is working well... Is a problem with your code and your data. Here you have your Fiddle fixed.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8311/

Your render function in `ProductItemDetails` was making the check for length == 0 in something that is an object. Although you defined `selectedorderitem` in your ParentContainer as an array, when you are updating the state you are passing a specific object (and your product detail was expecting an array). Plus, something similar was happening in your `ProductItemLineDetails` (and the dataset is all the same regarding prices and product names, so I changed it a little bit so that you can see it works).

Comment: How do you guys know all this things?? really. it works like a charm. I will compare the changes you made to my original but at least i have a base to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s because you are logging the state before it’s actually updated:

```
handleUserInput: function(orderitem){
  this.setState({
    selectedorderitem: orderitem
  });
  console.log("setstate hit",  this.state.selectedorderitem);
  console.log("setstate order", orderitem);
}
```

Should be:

```
handleUserInput: function(orderitem){
  this.setState({
    selectedorderitem: orderitem
  }, function() {
    console.log("setstate hit",  this.state.selectedorderitem);
    console.log("setstate order", orderitem);
  })
}
```

Comment: Ok i tested the way that you advised and it still didn't work, even removed the logs entirely and the same results. However my main issue is that the detailview is not updated though there is an update to state.

Comment: I too have the same issue. did you found any solution for that @NnamdiJibunoh